# Populating listView Async

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

This is my problem:

I get phone's gps coordinates and I use them with Google Directions API to get the distance between phone and some buildings from my town. The buildings position is stored in an xml file.

I use an asyncTask to loop all the buildings coordinates and get the distance between building and phone from google api.

The problem is that sometimes when I got many buildings it takes to long to finish all the request and after that to show the list, and I would like to know how to do this:

How can I update listView each time a request is completed:

For example: first time the list is empty, i make a request to google api and I get 1 item in the list and then another request. This way I don't need to wait untill All the request are finished.

I think that if I have 20 buildings coordinates is not a solution to create 20 instance of async Task.

Thank You, 
Catalin

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way IMO is calling notifyDataSetChanged() within runOnUiThread():

```
private class DownloadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Recording, Void> {

  protected Void doInBackground(Void... parms) {
    for (DownloadTask task: tasks) {
      DownloadData downloadData = downloadSomething(task);
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          listAdapter.add(downloadData);
          listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
      });
    }
  } // end of doInBackground()
}
```

Hope that help.

Comment: or use publishProgress from inside doInBackground and handle it on the UI thread inside onProgressUpdate

Comment: @FunkTheMonk, Yeah, that is more OO way, though need carry/pass param/object between doInBackground() and onProgressUpdate(), probably not the simplest way:)